# VSCode + Github, No initalize repository button

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, github-for-windows

Following several tutorials, but run into the same issue. I expect it's something simple, but I'm new to git and Visual Studio Code. I'm on Win10.

The "initialize repository" button mentioned everywhere is not there, just "SOURCE CONTROL" then a text box with "Message(Ctrl + Enter to commit on..." inside, then Changes with a 0.

I follow this to the one minute mark but don't have the button. Every other tutorial assumes you have it. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ik3wFSyFaNc&t=60s

I've tried closing all folders and editors, and opening a folder, but it's not there.

When I close and open VSCode, the buttons in Source Control are are "Open Folder, and "Clone repository", with "no folder opened" in caps. When I open a folder from that button, it's the same, source control has no initialize button. The folder that I'm opening is empty (just created as per the vid tutorial).

What I expect (left side): [image: git option]

What I get: [image: no option]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I look at the second screen grab for "What I get", doesn't it already show that you are in a branch "master" in the bottom left? The video you mention has it as "main". It looks like you have already initialized it as "master".

Comment: @Fio, in the video you uploaded (https://youtu.be/QSXqwFOiftY) I see that you are creating a folder under "...\GitHub\Repositories" called "test", but these folders ("Repositories" and "test", and others) are all sub-folders of "...\GitHub" which DOES have the ".git" hidden folder (you first see it at 0:13)... and so it would appear that you are already in a (parent) folder that is source-controlled as "master" (in your case).

Comment: Jonno, That's it! I deleted the folder tried again and am seeing the expected behavior. Thank you so much!

Comment: For anyone else that experiences this issue... @Fio deleted the `.git` folder which existed in a (grand)parent folder, allowing her to continue and create a new git repository in the subfolder. 

In her case I suspect deleting the existing `.git` folder wasn't too critical... but in another scenario - you may first want to connect to that repo and make sure there are no records of pending (staged) changes that have not yet been committed.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your %PATH% environment variable does include `git.exe`

When you launch VSCode in that environment, it should detect Git and proposes all Git-related options, like initializing a repository.

Comment: git --version in VSCode terminal, outputs the installed version (git version 2.31.1.windows.1), so I think the %PATH% is correct. Right?

Comment: @Fio Yes, that is a good sign. For testing, can you install the GitLens plugin?

Comment: Here's a video of what im seeing. The created folder is empty (no hidden files)
https://youtu.be/QSXqwFOiftY (still uploading at time of post)

Then i installed gitlens as requested. I'd rather just get git working wihout relying on an extension though.

Comment: @Fio Did you check Jonno's answer? You won't see "Initialize repositiory" if you are alrteady in a repository.